# How to display the horizontal line completely using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have asked a question earlier.Here is the link:[how to add a vertical line using theme() function in my plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352281/how-to-add-a-vertical-line-using-theme-function-in-my-plot)

And now new problem happened,the horizontal line of the band6 can not display completely.Anyone can give me some suggestions?Thank you.

And my code is below:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = df1$MeanDecreaseAccuaracy, y = reorder(factor(df1$Variables),df1$MeanDecreaseAccuaracy)))

p + geom_segment(aes(yend = df1$Variables,xend = 0)) + 
geom_point() + 
theme_minimal() + 
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0),breaks = c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45)) + 
labs(x = "Mean Decrease in Accuracy",y = "Prdictors variable") + 
theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"),
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(size = 0.2,colour = "black"),
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(size = 0.2,colour = "black"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

And the output figure is as follows.
[image]

Comment: You can either change your x axis limits with `limits`, e.g., `limits = c(0, 45)`, or use something other than 0 values in `expand`.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028825/ggplot2-force-y-axis-to-start-at-origin-and-float-y-axis-upper-limit) close relative, maybe not duplicate.

Comment: **Don't** use `data$column` inside `aes()`. It will cause problem if you try to facet or use other advanced features. You should have `aes(x = MeanDecreaseAccuracy, y = reorder(factor(Variables, MeanDecreaseAccuracy)))`. To solve your problem, I would recommend setting `limits = c(0, 1.05 * max(df1$MeanDecreaseAccuracy))`. (Note that is *not* inside `aes()` so you do need to use the `data$column` identifier).

Comment: Hi Gregor,Thank you very much.Your answer works well.

Comment: So post as an answer? And mark it correct? That is how the site is supposed to work you know.

Comment: Use 'limits=c(0,45)'

Answer (score 1):

Okay, posting as answer:

**Don't** use `data$column` inside `aes()`. It will cause problems if you try to facet or use other advanced features. You should have

```
aes(x = MeanDecreaseAccuracy,
    y = reorder(factor(Variables, MeanDecreaseAccuracy)))
```

To solve your problem, I would recommend setting `limits = c(0, 1.05 * max(df1$MeanDecreaseAccuracy))`. inside your `scale_x_continuous`. (Note that is *not* inside `aes()` so you do need to use the `data$column` identifier here).